# Firebase Web - Google sign-in with "redirect" option not redirecting but "popup" option works. What am I missing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Google sign-in with firebase web for my vuejs app. Firebase's google sign-in gives two options - with [redirect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#redirect-mode) and [popup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#popup-mode) to sign in. After successful sign-in, I want to redirect the user to a specific page. This works with pop-up method but with redirect, it signs in the user but comes back to the login page. Is there a property I need to set to get this working? My code snippet below:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
// This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
   var token = result.credential.accessToken;
// The signed-in user info.
   var user = result.user;
   that.navToLogin();   //---> this works with signInWithPopup
});

firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function(result) {
 //user gets signed in but it does not redirect to a new page
   that.navToLogin(); //---> this does not work
});

//Below didn't work either:

firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
 if (result.credential) {
   // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
   var token = result.credential.accessToken;
   that.navToLogin(); //---> this does not work
 }
 // The signed-in user info.
 var user = result.user;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be duplicated. You can get an explanation about how redirecting behaves here:

[Firebase Google signInWithRedirect not redirecting to specified page on successful authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967942/firebase-google-signinwithredirect-not-redirecting-to-specified-page-on-successf)

Comment: If it's a duplicate question, please flag it as a duplicate instead of posting this info as an answer. You could also post this as a comment underneath the question, but this answer will probably end up deleted as a link only answer.